# How to programmatically invalidate remember-me cookie on Grails Spring Security Core?

Tags: facebook, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

Let's say a user logs in to the web-app using Spring Security Facebook and the remember-me cookie is generated and valid for 30 days but on the 10th day I want to revoke access to the user (disabled it in some way, one way would be to change to `enabled = false`)

How could I mark the user's cookie as no longer valid?
Is there even a way to do that?

In Config.groovy I have:

`grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.alwaysRemember=true`

I'm using:

- Grails 2.2.4
- Spring Security Core 1.2.7.3
- Spring Security Facebook 0.15.2

Many thanks

**Update:** actually, it looks like the remember-me cookie does not work with the Spring Security Facebook plugin

Answer (score 0):

`session.invalidate()`

and remove the security context associated with the user and the session

`SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()`

Comment: I belive that applies when doing it for the user that is logged in but how would it be done for another user (different from the one that is logged in)?